# Web Project Templates not appearing in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, durandal

I'm evaluating single-page application frameworks, and I've just downloaded and installed the various templates from [ScottGu's page](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2013/02/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2012-2-update.aspx).

However, when I attempt to create a "New ASP.NET MVC 4 Project", as detailed on the Durandal page, [here](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Visual-Studio-Project-Template.html), I see only the default, Visual Studio-installed templates.

I've checked in `C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\Extensions`, and I can see a directory (called `eislr0na.wgk`) containing the Durandal bits. I've deleted the .cache files in the `Extensions` folder and restarted Visual Studio.

But, I can't see any of the single-page templates in the dialog box.

What's the problem?

Comment: Did you install the Visual Studio 2012.2 update first? http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=282650

Comment: I thought I had, but it turns out that the installer was hiding under another window, and hadn't done its thing yet. Once I let it finish, the templates appeared...

Comment: So, if you put that as an answer, I'll accept it, and it'll be here for anyone else with the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use the new templates you must have the [Visual Studio 2012.2 update](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=282650) installed.